# google maps v3 not displaying all markers, please assist

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a list of latitudes and longitudes in a report which go through GeoCode and I'm using HTML tag to display it on google map but not all markers display on the map. only the first few appear on the map.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 700px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.756, -73.986);

var options = {center : latlng,zoom : 5,mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

// Creating the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow;

function displayLocation(a) {displayMap(a, 0);}

function displayInfo(a) {displayMap(a, 1);}

function displayMap(address, displayInfo) 

{geocoder.geocode( {'address' : address}, function(results, status) {


if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {


map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);


var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {


map : map,



position : results[0].geometry.location});



if (!infowindow) {  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();}



infowindow.setContent(address);


if (displayInfo == 1) {infowindow.open(map, marker);}



} else {// alert("Incorect adress: " +status+address);}
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code I think the following line returns `false` at some point

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
```

you do have an `else` statment, but this isn't closed correctly. The comment `// alert` also comments out the `}`

So you probably need to change this to

```
else {
    // alert("Incorect adress: " +status+address);
}
```

instead of

```
else {// alert("Incorect adress: " +status+address);}
```